# Angular ng ui grid grid causing horizontal scrolling of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to implement ng ui grid but is when i embed it then whole page become horizontally scrollable.

Here is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head >
  <title>ISS Core</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!--angular grids based ependency  -->

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
  <style>

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}





  /* angular grip based dependency */




/*$scope.getTableHeight = function() {
   var rowHeight = 30; // your row height
   var headerHeight = 30; // your header height
   return {
      height: ($scope.gridData.data.length * rowHeight + headerHeight) + "px"
   };
};

$scope.$watchCollection('tableData', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.grid')).css($scope.getTableHeight());
});

*/  </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.selection']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $q) {
  var fakeI18n = function( title ){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $interval( function() {
      deferred.resolve( 'col: ' + title );
    }, 1000, 1);
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  $scope.gridOptions = {
     multiSelect : false,
    exporterMenuPdf : false,
    enableHiding : false,
    enableColumnMenus : false,
    enableHiding : false,

    enableGridMenu : false,
    gridMenuTitleFilter: fakeI18n,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name' },
      { name: 'gender', enableHiding: false },
      { name: 'company' }
    ],
    gridMenuCustomItems: [
      {
        title: 'Rotate Grid',
        action: function ($event) {
          this.grid.element.toggleClass('rotated');
        },
        order: 210
      }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

      // interval of zero just to allow the directive to have initialized
      $interval( function() {
        gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{ title: 'Dynamic item', order: 100}]);
      }, 0, 1);

      gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged( $scope, function( changedColumn ){
        $scope.columnChanged = { name: changedColumn.colDef.name, visible: changedColumn.colDef.visible };
      });
    }
  };

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}]);


</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" >



<div class="row" id="grid"  ng-controller="MainCtrl">  <h3 style="background-color: #0a4e8f;color:white;">Arrival Flight List</h3>

 <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
  <div ng-if='columnChanged'>
    Column Visibility Changed - name: {{ columnChanged.name }} visible: {{ columnChanged.visible }}
  </div>  
</div>
<br>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is snap shot 
[image]

how can remove this horizontal scrolling ? 
I tried with

```
body{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but it also remove scrolling from grid label.

Answer (score -1):

changes in ng ui grid css worked for me

```
.grid {
  width: 99.9%;
  height: 50vh;

}
```